# Custom Script started in bootup of Red Hat has child processes killed

Tags: linux, redhat

We are starting an application in the bootup of a Red Hat Linux (`enter code here`RHEL 7) server but the child processes that are started from this script are killed once the script finishes.  The Bash script is a very simple script:  It starts the app on this server (01) which will spawn several child processes, and then it starts the app on 2 other servers via ssh.  The processes on the remote servers are fine and do not get killed.
I can see the app is running for a few minutes while the script is starting the apps on those remote servers. I can list the processes and i can open the UI of the app.
However, once the script finishes - boom, the processes are killed hard.  The process ids just disappear.

The start script is started this way:
cat /etc/systemd/system/gis.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Sterling Integrator App startup
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/s10/sterling/uwwbin/startup_gis_nodes_master.sh
#ExecStart=/s10/sterling/strace-script.sh
User=gisuser
Group=gisuser

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer right after i posted this - so in case others are curious we had to add this parameter: RemainAfterExit=yes

So the whole script is:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/gis.service
[Unit]
Description=Sterling Integrator App startup
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/s10/sterling/uwwbin/startup_gis_nodes_master.sh
User=gisuser
Group=gisuser

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```